# Jquery this.val not work in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

IE 8 & IE11 there is alot of diff Can anyone help me why there is variance please?

Refer below Image link below for ie8 & 11 output difference & whole code :

http://postimg.org/image/e26ikiv1l/
(or) http://tinypic.com/r/2a4nxp3/8

Note : First alert works only in IE8 but second alert works in both IE8 & IE11

Reference java script code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $("a.explode").click(function(){
         var _rule = $(this).val(); 
         var _overrule =  $(this).attr('value'); 
         alert(_rule);
         alert(_overrule);
     });
});
```

Comment: anchor element do not have value.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use anchor tag.use button.

```
<button value="xyz" class="button_class">ABC</button>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".button_class").click(function(){
     var _rule = $(this).html(); 
     var _overrule =  $(this).attr('value'); 
     alert(_rule);
     alert(_overrule);
 });
});
```

see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ev1tctv/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[There is no `value` attribute for anchor elements in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1).

In IE8 the browser treats it as an expando-property and lets you access it through `.value` (which is what `.val()` reads).

In IE9 and later [this non-standard behaviour is removed](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/ie9-internet-explorer-9-changes-developers-should-know-about/).

The `.attr()` method reads the attribute directly from the DOM, so it can access it even though it is non-standard.

---

You should probably use [a `data-value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) and/or not use an anchor for this.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
         $("a.explode").click(function(){
         var _rule = $(this).parent().text();          
         alert(_rule);         
     });
});
```